# undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_attribute_set<char>::~basic_attribute_set()'

Tags: c++, boost, compiler-errors

Newbie question... I'm trying out Boost for the first time because I want to test drive the [Boost Log](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html) library. I built this test program...

```
#include <boost/log/trivial.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int fibonacci(int num) {
    int i;
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;

    for (i = 2; i <= num; ++i) {
        BOOST_LOG_TRIVIAL(info) << "Iteration " << i << " (a = " << a << ", b = " << b << ")...";
        b = a + b;
        a = b - a;
    }

    return a;
}

int main() {
    std::cout << "8th fibonacci number: " << fibonacci(8) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile data:

```
**** Build of configuration Debug for project LoggingCpp ****

make all 
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -lpthread -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o"main.o" "../main.cpp"
Finished building: ../main.cpp

Building target: LoggingCpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Linker
g++ -lpthread -o"LoggingCpp"  ./main.o   
./main.o: In function `~basic_logger':
/usr/include/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp:90: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_attribute_set<char>::~basic_attribute_set()'
./main.o: In function `boost::log_mt_posix::trivial::logger::construct_logger()':
/usr/include/boost/log/trivial.hpp:102: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::trivial::aux::init()'
./main.o: In function `void boost::call_once<void (*)()>(boost::once_flag&, void (*)())':
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/once.hpp:51: undefined reference to `boost::detail::get_once_per_thread_epoch()'
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/once.hpp:55: undefined reference to `boost::detail::once_epoch_mutex'
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/once.hpp:66: undefined reference to `boost::detail::once_epoch_mutex'
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/once.hpp:77: undefined reference to `boost::detail::once_global_epoch'
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/once.hpp:77: undefined reference to `boost::detail::once_global_epoch'
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/once.hpp:77: undefined reference to `boost::detail::once_global_epoch'
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/once.hpp:78: undefined reference to `boost::detail::once_epoch_cv'
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/once.hpp:84: undefined reference to `boost::detail::once_epoch_mutex'
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/once.hpp:84: undefined reference to `boost::detail::once_epoch_cv'
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/once.hpp:88: undefined reference to `boost::detail::once_global_epoch'
/usr/include/boost/thread/pthread/once.hpp:73: undefined reference to `boost::detail::once_epoch_cv'
./main.o: In function `record_pump':
/usr/include/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp:293: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::allocate_compound(boost::log_mt_posix::basic_record<char> const&)'
./main.o: In function `~auto_release':
/usr/include/boost/log/sources/record_ostream.hpp:280: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::release_compound(boost::log_mt_posix::aux::stream_provider<char>::stream_compound*)'
./main.o: In function `boost::log_mt_posix::sources::aux::logger_singleton<boost::log_mt_posix::trivial::logger>::init_instance()':
/usr/include/boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp:126: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::sources::aux::global_storage<char>::get_or_init(std::type_info const&, boost::function0<boost::shared_ptr<boost::log_mt_posix::sources::aux::logger_holder_base> > const&)'
/usr/include/boost/log/sources/global_logger_storage.hpp:147: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::odr_violation::throw_(char const*, unsigned long, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
./main.o: In function `boost::log_mt_posix::sources::aux::severity_level<boost::log_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>::set_value(boost::log_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level)':
/usr/include/boost/log/sources/severity_feature.hpp:95: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::sources::aux::set_severity_level(int)'
./main.o: In function `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_record<char> boost::log_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::open_record_unlocked<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> >(boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, boost::log_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level const> const&)':
/usr/include/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp:269: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_core<char>::open_record(boost::log_mt_posix::basic_attribute_set<char> const&)'
./main.o: In function `boost::log_mt_posix::sources::basic_logger<char, boost::log_mt_posix::sources::severity_logger_mt<boost::log_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>, boost::log_mt_posix::sources::multi_thread_model<boost::log_mt_posix::aux::light_rw_mutex> >::push_record_unlocked(boost::log_mt_posix::basic_record<char> const&)':
/usr/include/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp:280: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_core<char>::push_record(boost::log_mt_posix::basic_record<char> const&)'
./main.o: In function `basic_logger<boost::parameter::aux::tagged_argument<boost::log_mt_posix::keywords::tag::severity, const boost::log_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level> >':
/usr/include/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp:145: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_core<char>::get()'
/usr/include/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp:145: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_attribute_set<char>::basic_attribute_set()'
./main.o: In function `~pair':
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_pair.h:72: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_slim_string<char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_slim_string()'
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_pair.h:72: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_slim_string<char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_slim_string()'
./main.o: In function `basic_logger':
/usr/include/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp:135: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_core<char>::get()'
/usr/include/boost/log/sources/basic_logger.hpp:135: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_attribute_set<char>::basic_attribute_set(boost::log_mt_posix::basic_attribute_set<char> const&)'
./main.o: In function `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_attribute_set<char>::reference_proxy::operator=(boost::shared_ptr<boost::log_mt_posix::attribute> const&) const':
/usr/include/boost/log/attributes/attribute_set.hpp:121: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_slim_string<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_slim_string(char const*, unsigned long)'
/usr/include/boost/log/attributes/attribute_set.hpp:121: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_attribute_set<char>::insert(boost::log_mt_posix::basic_slim_string<char, std::char_traits<char> > const&, boost::shared_ptr<boost::log_mt_posix::attribute> const&)'
/usr/include/boost/log/attributes/attribute_set.hpp:121: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_slim_string<char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_slim_string()'
/usr/include/boost/log/attributes/attribute_set.hpp:121: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_slim_string<char, std::char_traits<char> >::~basic_slim_string()'
./main.o: In function `pair<std::basic_string<char>, boost::shared_ptr<boost::log_mt_posix::attribute> >':
/usr/include/c++/4.5/bits/stl_pair.h:116: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_slim_string<char, std::char_traits<char> >::basic_slim_string(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
./main.o: In function `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_attribute_set<char>::insert(std::pair<boost::log_mt_posix::basic_slim_string<char, std::char_traits<char> > const, boost::shared_ptr<boost::log_mt_posix::attribute> > const&)':
/usr/include/boost/log/attributes/attribute_set.hpp:507: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_attribute_set<char>::insert(boost::log_mt_posix::basic_slim_string<char, std::char_traits<char> > const&, boost::shared_ptr<boost::log_mt_posix::attribute> const&)'
./main.o: In function `boost::log_mt_posix::sources::aux::severity_level<boost::log_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>::dispatch(boost::log_mt_posix::type_dispatcher&)':
/usr/include/boost/log/sources/severity_feature.hpp:105: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::sources::aux::get_severity_level()'
./main.o: In function `boost::log_mt_posix::sources::aux::severity_level<boost::log_mt_posix::trivial::severity_level>::detach_from_thread()':
/usr/include/boost/log/sources/severity_feature.hpp:118: undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::sources::aux::get_severity_level()'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [LoggingCpp] Error 1
```

[About Boost Log syntax](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/tutorial.html#log.tutorial.trivial)

Did I install Boost Log incorrectly? Am I missing crucial libraries? Did I omit necessary linker flags?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you haven't built log?

Once you've copied the log header files, etc into the corresponding folders in your boost distro (keep the same structure i.e. merge the headers to the headers, the libs folder into the libs folder of your boost distro, etc), you still need to build boost and then like John mentioned, link against it. That's why the link you referred to above points you to the standard boost build instructions.

It's a while ago, but AFAIR on linux  you simply run `./bjam` in the root of your boost folder.

Comment: bjam in the root dir fails: `Unable to load Boost.Build: could not find "boost-build.jam"`. `libs/log` contains a few subdirectories including `build`, `src` and `doc`, so I don't think you can just copy its contents to `/usr/lib64`.

Comment: What I meant was you've downloaded a boost version from sourceforge and extracted it somewhere on your drive e.g. /home/user/boost_1_46 . Boost has a specific folder structure. If you download log and extract that, it has a similar structure. So copy all files from the logdir/boost dir to /home/user/boost_1_46/boost. Copy files in logdir/libs to /home/user/boost_1_46/libs, and so forth. Once you've done that invoke bjam as stated in 5.1 http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/more/getting_started/unix-variants.html If you invoke ./bjam install the lib files will be copied to your lib directory

Comment: I uninstalled Boost, freshly extracted Boost from its `.tar.bz2` and Boost Log from its `.zip`. I copied the dirs from Boost Log to the Boost root dir, then did `./bjam` and `./bjam install`. The compiler still isn't happy. http://pastebin.com/xTLQu9Cf

Comment: Did you check in the lib directory if the log libraries were built along with the other boost libraries? Also, you don't need to uninstall anything, I just rebuild things with bjam when I add in things from the sandbox. Not sure if it's possible to just build the log lib.

Comment: In your link I still don't see you linking against the logging lib. After building log, you still need link against it as John mentioned. First make sure that the log libraries were built though.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add something like `-lboost-log-mt` to your link line.

Comment: How do I know the name of the flags I need to add? (`-lboost-log-mt` doesn't get recognized by the linker.)

Comment: Try this: `ls /usr/lib/libboost*log*` and post what files you find.  I may have had the name of the library wrong for you, but the -l option is valid for gcc, as shown by your own use of `-lpthread`.

Comment: `ls: cannot access /usr/lib/libboost*log*: No such file or directory`... I already feared it was an installation issue. I copied `/boost/log` to `/usr/include/boost/` but I didn't know additional files were needed. Their install instructions (http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation.html) are a little vague...

Comment: They do say "the library must be built as a shared object" - you need to make sure you have that .so for Boost Log, then add it to your link line.  There's not a whole lot more to say about this I'm afraid, other than starting a new question like "How do I build Boost Log?"

Comment: D'oh... I don't know how I can build the library as an `.so` file, so I'm gonna need verbose build instructions. (Boost Log's install documentation isn't very helpful imho.) Should I change the question to "How do I build Boost Log?" or make a new one?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe switch unright version of the boost_log.

I have the same issue for undefined reference to "boost::log::**v2_mt_posix**::core::push_record_move(boost::log::v2_mt_posix::record&)"

I build the libboost_log by myself. And I use the nm to grep the push_record_move found that, "boost::log::**v2s_mt_posix**::core::push_record_move(boost::log::v2s_mt_posix::record&)"

From the experience of before, should add some cflag in the Makefile.