# Undefined reference - CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks

I am getting the following error while trying to build my code:

```
Lib/librtix_common.so||undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::missing_value::throw_(char const*, unsigned long, std::string const&)'|
```

I am using CodeBlocks. does this mean CodeBlocks cant find Lib/librtix_common.so ?

Any suggetsion oh how I can resolve it ?

Answer (score 0):

No, `librtrix` if fine. I think you need to build `boost` and link against it.
Check this

[undefined reference to `boost::log_mt_posix::basic_attribute_set<char>::~basic_attribute_set()'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566244/undefined-reference-to-boostlog-mt-posixbasic-attribute-setcharbasic-a)